# Apply template to powerpoint in Excel VBA from embedded template file

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to apply a template to a powerpoint through excel. The powerpoint template is embedded within my excel file via insert -> Object. I've successfully used the `.applytemplate` method to apply a template from file, but I cannot adjust the code to reference the embedded powerpoint template. I tried using OLEObject, but I'm afraid that isn't correct. Please review below code.

```
Sub ppCreate()

Dim myPP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppObj As OLEObject

' Create instance of PowerPoint
Set myPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

' For automation to work, PowerPoint must be visible
myPP.Visible = True


' Create a presentation
Set myPres = myPP.Presentations.Add

' Set slide view to Slide Only
myPP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

'Resize to 4:3
myPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = 2

'Add a slide
Set activeSlide = myPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

'Import Template

Worksheets("CBRDATA").Select
Set ppObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ppObj")       'NOT WORKING
myPres.ApplyTemplate (ppObj)                      'NOT WORKING
myPres.ApplyTemplate "C:\CBR_TEMPLATE_COVER.potx" 'WORKING
Worksheets("CBR").Select

End Sub
```

Update:

```
'Test if template exists in C:\
If Dir("C:\CBR_TEMPLATE_COVER.potx") = "" Then
    'Open/Save the embedded template to C:\
    Set tempPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    Worksheets("CBRDATA").OLEObjects("ppObj").Verb 0
    tempPP.Visible = True
    Set tempPres = tempPP.ActivePresentation
    tempPres.SaveCopyAs ("C:\CBR_TEMPLATE_COVER.potx")
    tempPres.Close
Else:
End If

' Create instance of PowerPoint
Set myPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ppObj")` is type `OLEObject`, not `PowerPoint.Presentation`.

```
Set ppObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ppObj")       'NOT WORKING
```

While manually double-clicking on the object *open* the POTX file (actually it opens a new blank PPTX using the POTX as template), your assignment statement above isn't doing any of that, it's trying instead to put an OLEObject where a Presentation is expected, and that will always fail.

So, how to "open" the OLEObject?  OLEObject has a `.Verb` method, and the following will perform the object's *default action*, which in the case of embedded package objects, is usally to "open" them.

**The Solution**

```
'Import Template
'## This should Open the template
Worksheets("CBRDATA").OLEObjects("ppObj").Verb 0         

'## Assign the ActivePresentation to your ppObj variable
Set ppObj = myPP.ActivePresentation
```

Editorializing: Embedded OLEObjects are notoriously problematic, and probably not an ideal place to story things like *document templates* :)

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer. Based on your final comment, I'm thinking maybe I should save the embedded document to file first then applytemplate from file.

Comment: My final comment was just a recommendation that **if** you're using the OLEObject as a sort of way to "share" and maintain the document template, that's probably not a best practice. I wouldn't advise trying to use VBA to do what you mentioned. If you want to open the POTX from disk, then you should distribute the POTX and either retrieve it from a *known or highly-anticipated location* such as `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes`, or allow the user to select it with a `FileDialog`.

Comment: The document is part of a larger dashboard which creates standardized powerpoints based on user selections. I changed my code to test for the existance of the template in C:\, if it was not found, it creates a new powerpoint and saves it to that folder. The rest of my code doesn't need to be touch in that case. Details provided above. Thanks again for your help